# Jinja Python Flask - If name == x then name shall be something else

Tags: python, html, api, flask, jinja2

So I am working on a project here, now there are a few products that are named weirdly (so they work with Minecraft), but I want those products to display the real Minecraft Item, there are a total of 15 products, here is those products and the name they shall be:

```
"INK_SACK:3",  # cocao beans
"INK_SACK:4",  # lapis lazuli
"ENCHANTED_HUGE_MUSHROOM_1",  # enchanted brown mushroom block
"ENCHANTED_HUGE_MUSHROOM_2",  # enchanted red mushroom block
"HUGE_MUSHROOM_1",  # brown mushroom block
"HUGE_MUSHROOM_2",  # red mushroom block
"LOG_2:1",  # dark oak
"RAW_FISH:3",  # pufferfish
"RAW_FISH:2",  # clownfish
"RAW_FISH:1",  # raw salmon
"LOG:1",  # spruce
"LOG:3",  # jungle
"LOG:2",  # birch
"LOG",  # oak
"WATER_LILY",  # lily pad
"LOG_2",  # acacia
"ENDER_STONE",  # end stone
```

I need to change them to DISPLAY the names to the right on only those products that looks weird, my HTML code (using Jinja) looks like this:

```
{% block content%}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Buy Price</th>
      <th>Sell Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for product in products %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ product.id|replace("_", ' ')|lower()|title() }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.buy_price|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.sell_price|round(1, 'floor') }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

So the name of the products are displayed at "product.id", and I need a little "check" that if the product.id is for example "INK_SACK:3" it should display Cocao Beans instead. I could do a ton of IF statements, but I would like to have this non-hard coded (if possible).

Also, here is my python code:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
import datetime
import os

product_names = [This is just an array of all the 190+ products, removed them to make this thread shorter]

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def price():
    f = requests.get(
        "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[cant show API key]").json()
    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["quick_status"]["sellPrice"],
            "buy_price": product["quick_status"]["buyPrice"]
        }
        for product in f["products"].values()
    ]
    return render_template("index.html", products=products)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to create a new jinja filter. Define this in your main app file:

```
def product_lookup(product_id):
    product_dictionary = {'INK_SACK:3': 'Cocoa Beans'} #etc...
    name_override = product_dictionary.get(product_id)
    return name_override if name_override else product_id

app.jinja_env.filters['product_lookup'] = product_lookup
```

And then in your template:

```
<td>{{ product.id|product_lookup }}</td>
```

Comment: Not by my pc right now but I will give it a try later! Thanks :)

Comment: okay, one question tho. Will this work even though some products have the correct name? I only want the products I listed to be changed. And will it give the correct prices?

Comment: @SimonSjöö I updated the code to return the correct name if the value is not defined. Regarding prices, I didn't address that, so those lines would stay the same in your template. You'd just replace the line in the template pertaining to the name of the product with the one I provided.

Comment: "Method 'jinja_env' has no 'filters' member. Do I need to import something else from Flask?

Comment: That sounds like a pylint issue, not a real error: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/34720/pset8-2019-jinja-env-filters-error

Comment: cant see to get it to work, its telling me to make a file called ".pylintrc", I did and put in the text, now it created way more issues, all of my modules stopped working, don't think this might be the solution :( This issue here is not really a priority though, I have another major issue at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61941491/13581693