# Python list indices integers or slices

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I know there is a thread about this, I read it through multiple times and tried what was answered but it did not work for me. Now my Python code looks like this:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

product_names = [list of products, removed it as it makes thread longer, I have these here just to see what products there are]

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def price():
    f = requests.get(
        "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[supposed to be secret]").json()
    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["sell_summary"]["pricePerUnit"],
            "buy_price": product["buy_summary"]["pricePerUnit"],
            "sell_volume": product["quick_status"]["sellVolume"],
            "buy_volume": product["quick_status"]["buyVolume"],
            "buy_orders": product["quick_status"]["buyOrders"],
            "sell_orders": product["quick_status"]["sellOrders"]
        }
        for product in f["products"].values()
    ]
    return render_template("index.html", products=products)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now the problem comes from "["sell_summary"]["pricePerUnit"]", and I tried to do [0] and [:] In between sellsummary and priceperunit, I think it doesn't work as I am in an array?

I am doing this in Flask, using Jinja

Comment: do you have an example for `f`?

Comment: What do you mean? I have the f = request.get , do you mean instead of "product"? I got help with that code up there and it seem to be working, I'll have to do some more research! But the issue is that I can't return the "pricePerUnit", the priceperunit is a float value from the API, and I am getting "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when I do sell_summary and buy_summary. I had "quick_status" there as well from the beginning, but saw that it gave the wrong price!

Comment: I think that "product" in before ["quick_status"] is the product names, the JSON file for the API goes products => PRODUCT_ID => quick_status => sellVolume

Comment: Could you print `f["products"].values()`, before assigning it to `products`? I guess you will find your answer.

Comment: no, it doesn't look like it. I tried to save that into a variable, then printing that out but it gave nothing.